# Looking to automate seller login portal with Python and Selenium , find xPath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am looking for xPath for the image that I am inserting.

Below is the code that I wrote, everything is working except click on Login Button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\byteMe\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://seller.abc.com/')
browser.find_element_by_id('Final').click()
browser.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys('byteme@gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('byteme')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@'button']").click()
browser.get('https://seller.abc.com/index.html#dashboard/listings-management?listingState=ACTIVE')
```

Inspect element code

[image]

Comment: Your site can’t be reached

Comment: well i removed website link. its a wellknown eCommerce portal and I do not want to share the link

Comment: But u can surely check the image that I inserted. Sorry

Comment: You could use a recorder to find the best xpath of you elements.Something like Katalon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code to click on a login button

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


submit=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sc-aewfc iesYjz']//span")))
submit.click()
```